# How to use Free with steams in fs2?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, free-monad, fs2

Let's say I want to read data from jms, map it through `toUpperCase` and send elsewhere. So I abstract over the actual messaging system with `Jms[A]`, right?

```
 trait Jms[A]    
 case object Pull extends Jms[String]    
 case class Push(s: String) extends Jms[Unit]
```

The business logic:

```
  def freeProcess(source: Stream[Jms, String], sink: Sink[Jms, String]): Free[Jms, Unit] =
    source.map(_.toUpperCase).through(sink).runFree
```

`Free` is to be interpreted, so be it:

```
 val interpreter = new ~>[Jms, Task] {
    def apply[A](f: Jms[A]): Task[A] = f match {
      case Pull => Task.now {
        /* await on socket;  toString */
        "incoming"
      }
      case Push(m: String) => Task.now {
        /* push to socket */
        ()
      }
    }
  }
```

But, what to pass to the `freeProcess`? What *are* these `source`/`sink`? Aren't the implementations in `interpreter` doing all the job? Can't I just forget about `Stream`s then?

How to actually use `Free` here?

Comment: Related: https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/05/09/tagless-final-streaming.html